# Flatten nested objects using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looping over object with a property set to array, which i then use in the following way:

```
  let merged= [];
  for (let sup of superObject) {
    let sname = sup.superObjectName;
    for (let sub of sup.subObject) {
      merged.push({superObject: sname, subObject: sub.subObjectName})
    }
  }
```

Now the code above works and get job done but i feel it can be improved using Lodash and i cant get it to work. i tried using `flatMap` in few different ways but  none seem to work, and the one in the right direction in terms of functionality wont seem like an improvement at all. 
Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** 
`superObject` example:

```
{
   superObjectName: "someName",
   subObject: [
      {subObjectName: "someSubName"},
      {subObjectName: "someSubName2"}
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Please add an example of the data you use, and the expected result.

Comment: Edit your question and add what you are getting in `superObject`

Comment: There is `Array.prototype.flat`, avoid useless libraries to keep the best performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the same as your code:

```
const merged = _.flatMap(superObject, ({superObjectName, subObject}) =>
    _.map(subObject, ({subObjectName}) => ({
        superObject: superObjectName,
        subObject: subObjectName
    }))
);
```

Each value in `superObject` transformed to Array with `map`, and then flattened inside `flatMap`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap), get props and get the desire result like this using lodash.

```js
var data= [{
   superObjectName: "someName",
   subObject: [
      {subObjectName: "someSubName"},
      {subObjectName: "someSubName2"}
    ]
 }];

const result = _.flatMap(data, ({ superObjectName, subObject}) =>
  _.map(subObject, ({subObjectName})=> ({superObject: superObjectName, subObject: subObjectName}))
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```